# How i can download video from vk.com?

Tags: node.js, vk

I have link with video on [`https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-91050183&id=456334166&hash=60b6e13afe8cc455&__ref=vk.api&api_hash=1696331728e054a28710d03af6c9_G44TMNBRGEZTIMQ`](https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-91050183&id=456334166&hash=60b6e13afe8cc455&__ref=vk.api&api_hash=1696331728e054a28710d03af6c9_G44TMNBRGEZTIMQ)
now i try

```
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(`${path}/uploads/video.mp4`);

    return $api({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-91050183&id=456334166&hash=60b6e13afe8cc455&__ref=vk.api&api_hash=1696331416e3a913f9e47f8c530a_G44TMNBRGEZTIMQ.mp4',
      responseType: 'stream',
    }).then((response) => {
      //ensure that the user can call `then()` only when the file has
      //been downloaded entirely.

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data.pipe(writer);
        let error = null;
        writer.on('error', (err) => {
          error = err;
          writer.close();
          reject(err);
        });
        writer.on('close', () => {
          if (!error) {
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

But it doesn't work, it's understandable why, because we need a link to the video itself.mp4? How can I get it? Well, in which direction should I move? Thanks in advance for the answer❤

In my video.mp4 file, just some html document is downloaded if you open it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.